# Convert crosstab query into a view

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which I want to convert to a view:

```
SELECT
  PartNum,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '2', value, NULL)) AS 'Mon',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '3', value, NULL)) AS 'Tue',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '4', value, NULL)) AS 'Wed',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '5', value, NULL)) AS 'Thu',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '6', value, NULL)) AS 'Fri',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '7', value, NULL)) AS 'Sat',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '1', value, NULL)) AS 'Sun',
  SUM(IF(DeliveryDate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY), value, NULL)) AS 'Future'
FROM (
  SELECT PartNum, DeliveryDate , SUM(Ordered) value FROM v_archived_items_due
    GROUP BY PartNum, DeliveryDate
    ) t
  GROUP BY PartNum;
```

When I try to save it as a view, I get the following error:

> 1349 - Views SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause.

The query works fine by itself. How do I turn it into a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not allow subqueries in view so, without seeing any sample data to see how to rework this without the subqyery. Since this is working as expected, I would create a view of your subquery:

```
create view view1 as
    SELECT PartNum, DeliveryDate , SUM(Ordered) value 
    FROM v_archived_items_due
    GROUP BY PartNum, DeliveryDate;
```

Then just call this view in your query:

```
SELECT
  PartNum,
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '2', value, NULL)) AS 'Mon',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '3', value, NULL)) AS 'Tue',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '4', value, NULL)) AS 'Wed',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '5', value, NULL)) AS 'Thu',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '6', value, NULL)) AS 'Fri',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '7', value, NULL)) AS 'Sat',
  SUM(IF(DAYOFWEEK(DeliveryDate) = '1', value, NULL)) AS 'Sun',
  SUM(IF(DeliveryDate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY), value, NULL)) AS 'Future'
FROM view1
GROUP BY PartNum;
```

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you. BF, your solution worked like a charm!

Comment: @user1842670 if any of the answers are helpful be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Behavoiur as designed

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html

You have to build a view from your subquery and use this.